# How can I expand and collapse a <div> using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a list on my site.  This list is created by a foreach loop that builds with information from my database.  Each item is a container with different sections, so this is not a list like 1, 2, 3... etc.  I am listing repeating sections with information.  In each section, there is a subsection.  The general build is as follows:

```
<div>
    <fieldset class="majorpoints" onclick="majorpointsexpand($(this).find('legend').innerHTML)">
    <legend class="majorpointslegend">Expand</legend>
    <div style="display:none" >
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I am trying to call a function with onclick="majorpointsexpand($(this).find('legend').innerHTML)"

The div I am trying to manipulate is style="display:none" by default, and I want to use javascript to make it visible on click.

The "$(this).find('legend').innerHTML" is attempting to pass, in this case, "Expand" as an argument in the function.

Here is the javascript:

```
function majorpointsexpand(expand)
    {
        if (expand == "Expand")
            {
                document.write.$(this).find('div').style = "display:inherit";
                document.write.$(this).find('legend').innerHTML = "Collapse";
            }
        else
            {
                document.write.$(this).find('div').style = "display:none";
                document.write.$(this).find('legend').innerHTML = "Expand";
            }
    }
```

I am almost 100% sure my problem is syntax, and I don't have much of a grasp on how javascript works.

I do have jQuery linked to the document with:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

In the `<head></head>` section.

Comment: I think what you are trying to achieve is an accordion http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: `$this` - where does this come from?

Comment: $this is me trying to say "in relation to" the HTML element that the function is triggered inside of.

Comment: @hungerpain - I think the asker may be new to jQuery and just forgot the parenthesis around `$(this)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you should study more about jQuery first. Apparently you don't know much about the difference between jQuery and JavaScript

Comment: @aokaddaoc you were absolutely right ;)

Comment: If you are just looking for the way to collapse, bootstrap collapse might serve well. 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Okay, so you've got two options here :

1. Use jQuery UI's accordion - its nice, easy and fast. See more info [here](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)
2. Or, if you still wanna do this by yourself, you could remove the `fieldset` (its not semantically right to use it for this anyway) and create a structure by yourself.

Here's how you do that. Create a HTML structure like this :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"><span>Expand</span>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this CSS: (This is to hide the `.content` stuff when the page loads.

```
.container .content {
    display: none;
    padding : 5px;
}
```

Then, using jQuery, write a `click` event for the header.

```
$(".header").click(function () {

    $header = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $content = $header.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        $header.text(function () {
            //change text based on condition
            return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
        });
    });

});
```

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/eK8X5/7/

Comment: +1 as this would solve the problem if there was more than one DIV element on the page. In other words, since you're targeting the content within the clicked header, this scales well.

Comment: The fieldset is not imperative.  I will get rid of it and just use a border.  This is excellent because it selects the div to expand relative to the header I've clicked, which is important because of the fact that I may have several different numbers of listed items depending on user settings and other factors.

Comment: @Unipartisandev look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/476Nq/
full fledged example :)

Comment: I really appreciate the help.  There will be other parts of the site that will no doubt need to use an accordion even though this one particular thing is more of an all or nothing display example.  I'm still having problems.  My jQuery was outdated and not loading.  That's fixed, but I still am not having it work.  I've messed with it for a good hour now, I'll sleep on it.  Maybe tomorrow it will hit me.

Comment: I love this, Is there any way to adjust this so that when you collapse and expand, to show original Name of the name... say I had "Dogs"... once I click it becomes "Expand / Collapse" ...I want it to say Dogs.

Comment: @Bain just remove the callback function of `slideToggle`, and you're set. http://jsfiddle.net/eK8X5/5223/

Comment: Thanks, works great for multiple divs. My concern now is to get a dynamic Expand/Collapse title that takes the first <span> from the div to make a title like "Expand - Section 1: Introduction" ... but I can't quite figure it out yet.

Comment: @josh.thomson late answer, but because I was searching for the same after reading the answer:replace `$header.text(function () {` by `$header.find('span').text(function () { ` to only replace the text of the span inside the header

Comment: @krishwader How to collapse/expand part of table? In case table is large and I want to hide a part of it by default, but have access to entire page under button. My try: http://jsfiddle.net/nfLhzxb7/1/

Answer (score 22):

how about:

#### jQuery:

```
$('.majorpoints').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.hider').toggle();
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div>
  <fieldset class="majorpoints">
    <legend class="majorpointslegend">Expand</legend>
    <div class="hider" style="display:none" >
        <ul>
            <li>cccc</li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KqFRu/7/)

This way you are binding the click event to the `.majorpoints` class an you don't have to write it in the HTML each time.

Comment: Hi raam86, I'd take this a step further and do a .find on the div using a class instead of an id. If the asker has several of these fieldsets on the page, he'll want to target the hider for the one related to the specific fieldset clicked on. Hope this helps! :) For instance, you could use .closest to get a reference to the parent div, then use .find to locate the div with a class="hider" instead.

Comment: I know it's 3am ;), but I just noticed you're still using id's in your jsFiddle. This could result in undefined behavior since the W3C spec says each id should be unique. If you change the hider to a class, then this would be more immune to bugs or odd, unexplained behavior in other browsers. Hope this helps!

Comment: it should actually be 
$('.majorpointslegend').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().find('.hider').toggle();
          });
OR else when any place in the fieldset is clicked, it will collapse.

Answer (score 9):

You might want to give a look at this simple Javascript method to be invoked when clicking on a link to make a panel/div expande or collapse.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle(elementId) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
    }
} 
</script>
```

You can pass the div ID and it will toggle between display 'none' or 'block'.

Original source on **snip2code** - [How to collapse a div in html](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/18734/)

Answer (score 7):

Many problems here

I've set up a fiddle that works for you: http://jsfiddle.net/w9kSU/

```
$('.majorpointslegend').click(function(){
    if($(this).text()=='Expand'){
        $('#mylist').show();
        $(this).text('Colapse');
    }else{
        $('#mylist').hide();
        $(this).text('Expand');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

So, first of all, your Javascript isn't even using jQuery.  There are a couple ways to do this. For example:

First way, using the jQuery `toggle` method:

```
<div class="expandContent">
        <a href="#">Click Here to Display More Content</a>
 </div>
<div class="showMe" style="display:none">
        This content was hidden, but now shows up
</div>

<script>  
    $('.expandContent').click(function(){
        $('.showMe').toggle();
    });
</script>
```

jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/pM3DF/

Another way is simply to use the jQuery `show` method:

```
<div class="expandContent">
        <a href="#">Click Here to Display More Content</a>
 </div>
<div class="showMe" style="display:none">
        This content was hidden, but now shows up
</div>

<script>
    $('.expandContent').click(function(){
        $('.showMe').show();
    });
</script>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2wfM/

Yet a third way is to use the `slideToggle` method of jQuery which allows for some effects.  Such as `$('#showMe').slideToggle('slow');` which will slowly display the hidden div.

Comment: Suppose he has more than one of these showMe elements on the page?  Remember, he's using a for loop to build a list of these, so targeting class="showMe" would only affect the first instance of that element. My suggestion is to reference the showMe element in relation to the one clicked. Then this would be a good solution. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Right, but he's using the loop to build the list in a series of `<li>` elements, not divs.  Either way, he could just use the element ID then to hide it.

Comment: You're thinking of the subsections and forgetting that there will be more of these. Each **section** is populated with li elements in a **subsection**. *"This list is created by a foreach loop that builds with information from my database. Each item is a container with different sections, so this is not a list like 1, 2, 3... etc. I am listing repeating sections with information. In each section, there is a subsection."* in short, he just merely showed you only one section, even though there will be more.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `toggle()` **jQuery** function :

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Also, `innerHTML` **jQuery** Function is `.html()`.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow!  You should show an example so you're answer is more complete. If the link were to break, your answer would still be useful to future visitors. Good luck! :)

Comment: Could you either edit to add an example or add this as a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try jquery,

```
  <div>
        <a href="#" class="majorpoints" onclick="majorpointsexpand(" + $('.majorpointslegend').html() + ")"/>
        <legend class="majorpointslegend">Expand</legend>
        <div id="data" style="display:none" >
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


function majorpointsexpand(expand)
    {
        if (expand == "Expand")
            {
                $('#data').css("display","inherit");
                $(".majorpointslegend").html("Collapse");
            }
        else
            {
                $('#data').css("display","none");
                $(".majorpointslegend").html("Expand");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

[Here there is my example of animation a staff list with expand a description.](http://jsfiddle.net/Intacto/dgpKU/5/)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .staff {            margin:10px 0;}
      .staff-block{       float: left; width:48%; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;}
      .staff-title{       font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, Serif; background-color: #1162c5; color: white; padding:4px; border: solid 1px #2e3d7a; border-top-left-radius:3px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; font-weight: bold;}
      .staff-name {       font-family: Myriad Web Pro; font-size: 11pt; line-height:30px; padding: 0 10px;}
      .staff-name:hover { background-color: silver !important; cursor: pointer;}
      .staff-section {    display:inline-block; padding-left: 10px;}
      .staff-desc {       font-family: Myriad Web Pro; height: 0px; padding: 3px; overflow:hidden; background-color:#def; display: block; border: solid 1px silver;}
      .staff-desc p {     text-align: justify; margin-top: 5px;}
      .staff-desc img {   margin: 5px 10px 5px 5px; float:left; height: 185px; }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
<!-- START STAFF SECTION -->
<div class="staff">
  <div class="staff-block">
    <div  class="staff-title">Staff</div>
    <div class="staff-section">
        <div class="staff-name">Maria Beavis</div>
        <div class="staff-desc">
          <p><img src="http://www.craigmarlatt.com/canada/images/security&defence/coulombe.jpg" />Maria earned a Bachelor of Commerce degree from McGill University in 2006 with concentrations in Finance and International Business. She has completed her wealth Management Essentials course with the Canadian Securities Institute and has worked in the industry since 2007.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="staff-name">Diana Smitt</div>
        <div class="staff-desc">
          <p><img src="http://www.craigmarlatt.com/canada/images/security&defence/coulombe.jpg" />Diana joined the Diana Smitt Group to help contribute to its ongoing commitment to provide superior investement advice and exceptional service. She has a Bachelor of Commerce degree from the John Molson School of Business with a major in Finance and has been continuing her education by completing courses.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="staff-name">Mike Ford</div>
        <div class="staff-desc">
          <p><img src="http://www.craigmarlatt.com/canada/images/security&defence/coulombe.jpg" />Mike: A graduate of École des hautes études commerciales (HEC Montreal), Guillaume holds the Chartered Investment Management designation (CIM). After having been active in the financial services industry for 4 years at a leading competitor he joined the Mike Ford Group.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="staff-block">
    <div  class="staff-title">Technical Advisors</div>
    <div class="staff-section">
        <div class="staff-name">TA Elvira Bett</div>
        <div class="staff-desc">
          <p><img src="http://www.craigmarlatt.com/canada/images/security&defence/coulombe.jpg" />Elvira has completed her wealth Management Essentials course with the Canadian Securities Institute and has worked in the industry since 2007. Laura works directly with Caroline Hild, aiding in revising client portfolios, maintaining investment objectives, and executing client trades.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="staff-name">TA Sonya Rosman</div>
        <div class="staff-desc">
          <p><img src="http://www.craigmarlatt.com/canada/images/security&defence/coulombe.jpg" />Sonya has a Bachelor of Commerce degree from the John Molson School of Business with a major in Finance and has been continuing her education by completing courses through the Canadian Securities Institute. She recently completed her Wealth Management Essentials course and became an Investment Associate.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="staff-name">TA Tim Herson</div>
        <div class="staff-desc">
          <p><img src="http://www.craigmarlatt.com/canada/images/security&defence/coulombe.jpg" />Tim joined his father&#8217;s group in order to continue advising affluent families in Quebec. He is currently President of the Mike Ford Professionals Association and a member of various other organisations.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- STOP STAFF SECTION -->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script language="javascript"><!--
//<![CDATA[
$('.staff-name').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
var lastItem;
    $('.staff-name').click(function(currentItem) {
        var currentItem = $(this);
      if ($(this).next().height() == 0) {
          $(lastItem).css({'font-weight':'normal'});
          $(lastItem).next().animate({height: '0px'},400,'swing');
          $(this).css({'font-weight':'bold'});
          $(this).next().animate({height: '300px',opacity: 1},400,'swing');
      } else {
          $(this).css({'font-weight':'normal'});
          $(this).next().animate({height: '0px',opacity: 1},400,'swing');
      }
      lastItem = $(this);
    });
//]]>
--></script>

</body></html>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Intacto/dgpKU/5/)**

Answer (score 2):

Since you have jQuery on the page, you can remove that `onclick` attribute and the `majorpointsexpand` function. Add the following script to the bottom of you page or, preferably, to an external .js file:

```
$(function(){

  $('.majorpointslegend').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle().text( $(this).is(':visible')?'Collapse':'Expand' );
  });

});
```

This solutionshould work with your HTML as is but it isn't really a very robust answer. If you change your `fieldset` layout, it could break it. I'd suggest that you put a `class` attribute in that hidden div, like `class="majorpointsdetail"` and use this code instead:

```
$(function(){

  $('.majorpoints').on('click', '.majorpointslegend', function(event){
    $(event.currentTarget).find('.majorpointsdetail').toggle();
    $(this).text( $(this).is(':visible')?'Collapse':'Expand' );
  });

});
```

Obs: there's no closing `</fieldset>` tag in your question so I'm assuming the hidden div is inside the fieldset.

Comment: You're correct.  There is a closing fieldset, but I missed it in my question.  It comes immediately after the closing inner </div> and before the closing outer </div>

Answer (score 1):

If you used the data-role collapsible e.g.

```
    <div id="selector" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
    html......
    </div>
```

then it will close the the expanded div

```
    $("#selector").collapsible().collapsible("collapse");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Pure Javascript

```js
const collapsableBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsable-toggle');

for (let index = 0; index < collapsableBtn.length; index++) {
    collapsableBtn[index].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        // e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        iterateElement = this;

        getCollapsableParent = iterateElement.parentElement;

        if(getCollapsableParent.classList.contains('show')) {
            getCollapsableParent.classList.remove('show')
            iterateElement.innerText = iterateElement.getAttribute('data-onCloseText');

        } else {
            getCollapsableParent.classList.add('show');
            iterateElement.innerText = iterateElement.getAttribute('data-onOpenText');
        }
    })
}
```

```css
.collapsable-container #expand {
   display:none;
}
.collapsable-container.show #expand {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapsable-container">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="collapsable-toggle" data-onOpenText="Hide First Content" data-onCloseText="Show First Content">Show First Content</a>
    <div id="expand">
        This is some Content
    </div>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="collapsable-container">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="collapsable-toggle" data-onOpenText="Hide Second Content" data-onCloseText="Show Second Content">Show Second Content</a>
    <div id="expand">
        This is some Content
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure javascript allowing only one expanded div at a time. It allows multi-level sub-expanders. The html only need the expanders contents. The javascript will create the expanders headers with the titles form the content data attribute and a svg arrow.

```
<style>
    /* expanders headers divs */
    .expanderHead {
        color: white;
        background-color: #1E9D8B;
        border: 2px solid #1E9D8B;
        margin-top: 9px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 3px;
        padding-left: 9px;
        cursor: default;
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .expanderHead:first-child {
        margin-top: 0 !important;
    }

    .expanderBody:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    }

    /* expanders svg arrows */
    .expanderHead svg > g > path {
        fill: none;
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 2;
        stroke-miterlimit: 5;
        pointer-events: stroke;
    }

    /* expanders contents divs */
    .expanderBody {
        border: 2px solid #1E9D8B;
        border-top: 0;
        background-color: white;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
        padding: 6px;
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    /* widget window */
    .widget {
        width: 400px;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 9px;
        border: 2px solid #1E9D8B;
        border-top-left-radius: 6px;
        border-top-right-radius: 6px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    }

</style>
```

```
<div class="widget">

    <div data-title="expander 1" class="expanderBody">
        expander 1 content
    </div>

    <div data-title="expander 2" class="expanderBody">
        expander 2 content
    </div>

    <div data-title="expander 3" class="expanderBody">

        <div>
            expander 3 content
        </div>

        <div data-title="expander 3.1" class="expanderBody">
            expander 3.1 content
        </div>

        <div data-title="expander 3.2" class="expanderBody">
            expander 3.2 content
        </div>

        <div data-title="expander 3.3" class="expanderBody">
            expander 3.3 content
        </div>

    </div>

</div>



<script>
    document.querySelectorAll(".expanderBody").forEach(item => {
        if (item.dataset.title) {
            // create expander header
            let divHeader = document.createElement("div");
            divHeader.className = "expanderHead";
            divHeader.innerHTML = "<svg width='14px' height='8px' viewBox='0 0 12 6'><g><path d='M 5 5 L 10 1'/><path d='M 1 1 L 5 5'/></g></svg>&nbsp;<span>" + item.dataset.title + "</span>";
            // expander click event
            divHeader.addEventListener("click", function () {
                // open / close expander
                for (let i = 0; i < this.parentNode.children.length; i++) {
                    let expander = this.parentNode.children[i];
                    // check if it's expander header
                    if (expander.className == "expanderHead") {
                        if (expander == this && expander.nextElementSibling.style.display == "none") {
                            // open expander body
                            expander.nextElementSibling.style.display = "";
                            expander.innerHTML = "<svg width='14px' height='8px' viewBox='0 0 12 6'><g><path d='M 1 5 L 5 1'/><path d='M 5 1 L 10 5'/></g></svg>&nbsp;<span>" + expander.nextElementSibling.dataset.title + "</span>";
                            expander.style.borderBottomLeftRadius = "0";
                            expander.style.borderBottomRightRadius = "0";
                        }
                        else {
                            // close expander body
                            expander.nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
                            expander.innerHTML = "<svg width='14px' height='8px' viewBox='0 0 12 6'><g><path d='M 5 5 L 10 1'/><path d='M 1 1 L 5 5'/></g></svg>&nbsp;<span>" + expander.nextElementSibling.dataset.title + "</span>";
                            expander.style.borderBottomLeftRadius = "6px";
                            expander.style.borderBottomRightRadius = "6px";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, true);
            item.parentNode.insertBefore(divHeader, item);
            item.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of what your code does and why it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Jed Foster's [Readmore.js](http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/) library.

It's usage is as simple as:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('article').readmore({collapsedHeight: 100});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fastcdn.org/Readmore.js/2.1.0/readmore.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<article>
  <p>From this distant vantage point, the Earth might not seem of any particular interest. But for us, it's different. Consider again that dot. That's here. That's home. That's us. On it everyone you love, everyone you know, everyone you ever heard of, every human being who ever was, lived out their lives. The aggregate of our joy and suffering, thousands of confident religions, ideologies, and economic doctrines, every hunter and forager, every hero and coward, every creator and destroyer of civilization, every king and peasant, every young couple in love, every mother and father, hopeful child, inventor and explorer, every teacher of morals, every corrupt politician, every "superstar," every "supreme leader," every saint and sinner in the history of our species lived there – on a mote of dust suspended in a sunbeam.</p>

  <p>Space, the final frontier. These are the voyages of the starship Enterprise. Its five year mission: to explore strange new worlds, to seek out new life and new civilizations, to boldly go where no man has gone before!</p>

  <p>Here's how it is: Earth got used up, so we terraformed a whole new galaxy of Earths, some rich and flush with the new technologies, some not so much. Central Planets, them was formed the Alliance, waged war to bring everyone under their rule; a few idiots tried to fight it, among them myself. I'm Malcolm Reynolds, captain of Serenity. Got a good crew: fighters, pilot, mechanic. We even picked up a preacher, and a bona fide companion. There's a doctor, too, took his genius sister out of some Alliance camp, so they're keeping a low profile. You got a job, we can do it, don't much care what it is.</p>

  <p>Space, the final frontier. These are the voyages of the starship Enterprise. Its five year mission: to explore strange new worlds, to seek out new life and new civilizations, to boldly go where no man has gone before!</p>
</article>
```

Here are the available options to configure your widget:

```js
{
  speed: 100,
  collapsedHeight: 200,
  heightMargin: 16,
  moreLink: '<a href="#">Read More</a>',
  lessLink: '<a href="#">Close</a>',
  embedCSS: true,
  blockCSS: 'display: block; width: 100%;',
  startOpen: false,

  // callbacks
  blockProcessed: function() {},
  beforeToggle: function() {},
  afterToggle: function() {}
},
```

Use can use it like:

```js
$('article').readmore({
  collapsedHeight: 100,
  moreLink: '<a href="#" class="you-can-also-add-classes-here">Continue reading...</a>',
});
```

I hope it helps.