# trying to collapse text

Tags: javascript, html, text, collapsable

I am using this code

```
<div>
    <fieldset class="majorpoints" onclick="majorpointsexpand($this.find('legend').innerHTML)">
    <legend class="majorpointslegend">Expand</legend>
    <div style="display:none" >
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and when I add multiples of this code to a page it only open the first one.

I am needing around 20 lines of text that open and collapse when the titles are clicked. 
If interested in the purpose I am trying to clean up a simple webpage 
http://www.cranebbc.org/what-we-believe

any help would be great

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460116/expand-and-collapse-a-div-using-javascript

Comment: also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095933/pure-css-collapse-expand-div