# Toggle Div tag inside a datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlDataList" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <p>
                <h4>
                    <div class="ntitle" id='<%# Eval("Email_ID") %>'>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label30" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("Departure_Country") %>'></asp:Label>
                        -
                        <asp:Label ID="Label31" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("Arrival_Country") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </h4>
            </p>
            <div class="ncontent" id='d<%# Eval("Email_ID") %>'>
                <asp:Label ID="Label32" runat="server" Text="Company Name" Width="250px"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="Label33" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("comp_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label34" runat="server" Text="Contact Person" Width="250px"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="Label35" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("contact_person") %>'></asp:Label>
                <br />
                `enter code here`
            </div>
            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
                $("div.ntitle").click(function () {
                    debugger;
                    // $(this).closest('div').next('.ncontent').slideToggle();
                    $(this).next('.ncontent').slideToggle();
                });
            </script>
```

I have one datalist with two div tags. I write the code in javascript for click on one div it toggle the related next div. When I click on first div with class-name ntitle it not toggle the next div tag with class "ncontent".

Comment: do you on clicking on div with class name ntitle, it should toggle next div tag with class n content?

Comment: yes. i want to toggle the next div ncontent on click over ntitle

Comment: can you use this link as reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460116/expand-and-collapse-a-div-using-javascript

Comment: there are such 10 records fetching from database. And i want to toggle with only related div with class name "ncontent".

Comment: i just see this link . there are multiple explanations. and i tried some of them before. but not worked.

Comment: check the above code and please tell me the correction.. thank you shetty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery [**next**](https://api.jquery.com/next/) function finds the immediately following sibling of element (or the one if selector is passed) and here your `ncontent` div is not a sibling of  `ntitle`. Also since it is a  `DataList` control it will repeat itself dynamically. So here you can find the parent `row` (renderred by DataList control) and use it as context to find `ncontent` div. This will work as expected:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ntitle").click(function () {
         var parentRow = ($(this).parents('tr')); //find the parent row
         $('div.ncontent', parentRow).slideToggle(); //find ncontent div inside that row
    });
});
```

Comment: One Doubt about this is, I didnt write any "table"  or "tr", then how this code find out Parent "tr" here.

Comment: @vipul - Hey that's what I wrote in my answer, ASP.NET `DataList ` control renders as a html table. Just check the page source once the page loads, u will understand.