# Javascript to show/hide a particular child in a loop, depending on whose parent was clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am building a grid of projects, when you click on a particular `'project'` in the loop the div `'project_expanded'` needs to display, whilst hiding all other `'project_expanded'` divs.

I was planning on tackling this in jQuery with the show/hide function but I'm not sure the best way to get it to hide all other `'project_expanded'` divs aside from the one whose parent was clicked.

I believe each project in the loop may need a unique identifier eg item1, item 2, item 3 but as the list could potentially go on forever I am not sure how to get the Javascript to recognise all of these.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    <?php while( have_rows('portfolio') ): the_row(); 

                // vars
                $name = get_sub_field('name');
                $date = get_sub_field('date');
                $kit = get_sub_field('kit_used');
                $description = get_sub_field('description');
                $link = get_sub_field('video_url');
                $image = get_sub_field('image');
                $thumb = $image['sizes'][ 'large' ];
                ?>

                <?php 

                if( !empty($name) ):
                ?>
                <div class="project" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumb ?>');">
                    <div class="project_overlay">
                        <p class="prj_title"><?php echo $name; ?></p>
                        <p><?php echo $date; ?></p>
                        <p><?php echo $kit; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="project_expanded">
                    <h1><?php echo $name; ?> | <?php echo $date; ?></h1>
                    <p class="red_text"><?php echo $kit; ?></p>
                    <div data-type="youtube" data-video-id="<?php echo $link; ?>"></div>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: give them all the same class name, so "class="red_text expandable" & class="'prj_title expandable" and start by using jquery. there are several examples of expanding/collapsing divs with the same class. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/sVt7e/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460116/how-can-i-expand-and-collapse-a-div-using-javascript I found that fiddle through this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.project_expanded').hide();
  
  $(".project").click(function(){
    $('.project_expanded').hide();
    $(this).next('.project_expanded').show();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project" style="">
    <div class="project_overlay">
        <p class="prj_title">pr1</p>
        <p>DATE</p>
        <p>KIT</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="project_expanded">
    <h1>NAMEW | DATE</h1>
    <p class="red_text">KIT</p>
    <div data-type="youtube" data-video-id="LINK"></div>
</div>

<div class="project" style="">
    <div class="project_overlay">
        <p class="prj_title">pr2</p>
        <p>DATE1</p>
        <p>KIT1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="project_expanded">
    <h1>NAME2 | DATE2</h1>
    <p class="red_text">KIT</p>
    <div data-type="youtube" data-video-id="LINK"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`'hiding all except one'` -problems can be solved by hiding all, then show one.
To find out which one should be shown can be done by passing `this` (the element that was clicked) as parameter of the onclick method.

```
<div class="project" onclick="showProjectExpanded(this)">...</div>
```

in the js function you can search for the element you want to hide (in your case its a sibling with class project_expanded), hide all .project_expanded divs and show selected div.

```
function showProjectExpanded(project){
    var projectDiv = $.(project);  // not sure here, havent used jQuery for a long time ;)
    var divToShow = projectDiv.next();

    // hide all project_expanded divs
    $.('.project_expanded').hide();

    // show single project_expanded div
    divToShow.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation!