# How to expand and collapse multiple divs, without repeating the same code using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to write a code that expands and collapses a `div` with a paragraph, once you click the header text above it.

```
<div class="container">
<h3><span class="toggler">Text that toggles</span></h3>
<div class="wrapper">
<p>Random text</p>
</div>
</div>

 <div class="container">
<h3><span class="toggler2">Text that toggles</span></h3>
<div class="wrapper2">
<p>Random text</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I am aware that I could write a function like this which would toggle between `display: block` and `display: none`.

I could just repeat the same function for different divs with different classes and it would work, but if I have a lot of them I would end up repeating the same function multiple times and I feel like there has to be a much cleaner way to do this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".toggler").on("click", function() {
    $(".wrapper").toggleClass("active");
   });
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460116/how-can-i-expand-and-collapse-a-div-using-javascript

Comment: Use `$("[class^='toggler'")` as first selector and `$(this).find(".wrapper")` as second

Comment: The [attribute^=value] selector selects all elements with a title attribute value starting with value, you need to apply `$("[class^='toggler'").on("click", function(){  $(this).next(".wrapper").toggleClass("active");  });` in order to open all `.wrapper` in above code.

Comment: Vikintas Raudavicius did you checked my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to repeat it, give both a single class like "toggle-enabled" then instead of using toggler and toggler2 as two function you can put toggle-enabled as one selector and both will run the same function on click.

If you want to only toggle the one selected then use "this" keyword to get current and hide and show that or slide it whatever you want to do but dont need to repeat the code.

Here is your example code working as expected:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".toggle-enabled").on("click", function() {
   var nextdiv = $(this).parent().siblings("div");
   nextdiv.is(":visible")?nextdiv.hide():nextdiv.show();
 });
});
```

```css
.togglethis{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<h3><span class="toggler toggle-enabled">Text A that toggles</span></h3>
<div class="wrapper togglethis">
<p>Random text</p>
</div>
</div>

 <div class="container">
<h3><span class="toggler2 toggle-enabled">Text B that toggles</span></h3>
<div class="wrapper2 togglethis">
<p>I have left your toggler2 class in there and you can add more classes to separate it</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added parent to get to h3 from span but you can choose any selector to get to next div within that container or you can place a class on container to select that. The benefit of having a indexed selector is speed in finding it then traversing and searching.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need write single line of code if you use jquery & bootstrap.

**Solution 1:**

Add reference bnelow:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

your html:

```
<div class="container">
    <h3><span class="toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col1">Text that toggles</span></h3>
    <div class="wrapper" id="col1">
        <p>Random text</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <h3><span class="toggler2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col2">Text that toggles</span></h3>
    <div class="wrapper2" id="col2">
        <p>Random text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2:**

Either you can write simple line code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("h3").on("click", function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass("active");
 });
});
```

we can select header with **header Tag**. After that, we can add toogleClass to just next element that is "DIV".

so, when click header, toggleClass will be added to next element that is DIV

Comment: Why are you adding bootstrap? It has nothing to do with what the OP is askng.

Comment: you know class="container" is bootstrap class that's why adding.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for your html:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('[class^="toggler"]').on('click', function () { 
        $(this).closest('.container').children('[class^="wrapper"]').toggle();
     });
});
```

The code looks for any element on your html whose class name starts with `toggle`. It then attaches an on-click handler function. That function then looks for the affected element's closest ancestor with class name of `container`. Then from that ancestor/parent, it selects children with class name starting with `wrapper`. It then toggles the visibility of those children (or child)

You could give your togglers class names of `toggleN` (where N is any valid class name character) or simply `toggle` (same class name for all). Similarity,  you could name the classes for your wrappers as `wrapperN` or simply `wrapper`.