# How can I show a rule between elements even when they're hidden?

Tags: html, css

I would like to display lines between divs. In other words, I would like to draw a line on top of each divs, except the first one.

I wrote the following CSS that works well, except that some divs are hidden. Of course, since some divs are hidden, the selector `:not(:first-child)` no longer do the expected job. Is there a way to solve this issue in pure CSS?

I can't use `display: none` to hide the divs for 2 reasons.

- the elements are collapsible
- the elements must remain in the flow for text search purpose

```css
.item {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.item:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

.item.hide {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item hide">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item hide">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item ">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item hide">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item hide">Item 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you only have one visible div then how can you have a rule "between" it and another visible div? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: You mention in the comments your divs are collapseable. Please edit your question to add an [mcve] that includes the collapse functionality so we can see how you implement it. That is an important constraint for potential solutions.

Comment: @TylerH the project contains thousands of line. If I add the collapsible code + the search engine code. I think you don't realize how complex the snippet will be. I deliberately isolate the core of my problem. Many (too many) people don't answer the question, but tell me how to get around it or do something else. I know exactly what I'm doing. Despite your criticism, I still think the question is very precise.

Comment: You don't have to add the entire project, you just have to add enough code for your scenario to be reproducible. Collapsing HTML content should take you like 15 lines of code or less. Again, see [mcve] for more info. Posts can contain 30,000 characters, by the way, so your whole project could probably fit here if it were truly necessary.

Comment: 15 lines of code or less? I'll take your word for it. An animated collapse/expand div in the Bootstrap style. Without external library. Every semicolon must be followed by a carriage return. The content of the division must remain in the flow when collapsed. If the content of the div changes, the collapse must animate to the new height. And, icing on the cake, if you are able to do this properly without JavaScript, I send you 100 bucks!

Comment: Collapsing something in Bootstrap is a little over one line: just add the bootstrap CDN link to your head section and then add the `collapse` class to the element you want to collapse. In JS, it is *definitely* 15-20 lines (or less) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460116/how-can-i-expand-and-collapse-a-div-using-javascript

Comment: None of these solutions meets my specifications. Most of them use JQuery or Bootstrap which are external libraries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253852/discussion-between-fifi-and-tylerh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the next element ~ so that two consecutive item divs must not have the HIDE class to show the border.

```css
.item {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.item:not(.hide) ~ .item:not(.hide) {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

.item.hide {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item hide">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item hide">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item ">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item hide">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item hide">Item 1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

We can simply remove the border on the hidden divs if you want to keep them, but this leaves a divider at the last visible element

```css
.item { 
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.item:not(:first-child) { 
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}


.item.hide {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item hide">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item hide">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item ">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item hide">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item ">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item hide">Item 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly my problem, either the first or the last line remains. I only want lines between elements